# nodejs mongodb showing error..data has fetched from the database.. i have confirmed by log ing at the productHelpers...Here log not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

this is the code block ie not working

```
router.get('/edit-product/:id', async ( req, res) => {
    let product = await productHelper.getProductDetails(req.params.id)
    res.render('admin/edit-product', {product})
    })
```

this is the database output

```
{
  _id: 5fac281c98d153b05c08ab95,
  name: 'rice3',
  category: 'Grocery',
  description: ' rice ',
  price: '20'
}
```

THis is the output error message//

```
(node:13081) Unhandled romiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
   

at new ObjectID (/home/ali/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:59:11)
   

at ObjectID (/home/ali/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:40:43)
    at /home/ali/Desktop/webapp/helpers/product-helpers.js:34:79
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getProductDetails (/home/ali/Desktop/webapp/helpers/product-helpers.js:33:16)
    at /home/ali/Desktop/webapp/routes/admin.js:46:38
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ali/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ali/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ali/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ali/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
(node:13081) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
GET /stylesheets/index.css 304 4.690 ms - -
GET /admin/edit-product/index.css - - ms - -
```

Comment: `_id: 5fac281c98d153b05c08ab95` ... should be `_id: "5fac281c98d153b05c08ab95"` - since the error tells you that `Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`

Comment: are you doing any transformation in `getProductDetails` ?

Comment: getProductDetails fetch the data from mongodb database using findOne ..there is no error, that i did cosole.log there....

Comment: _id: 5fac281c98d153b05c08ab95 was the output from database

Comment: getProductDetails: (productid) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.get().collection(collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION).findOne({ _id: objectId(productid) }).then((product) => {
                console.log(product);
                resolve(product)
            })
        })
    },